# How to programmatically add new NSToolbarItem to existing toolbar?

Tags: cocoa, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

I'm looking for a method called `addNewItem:(NSToolbarItem *)item` or something like this that lets me add a programmatically created item to my toolbar, but I haven't found any. I would like to add an item that shows a popover when the user clicks on it, like in Safari when the user downloads something.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to have a class that conforms to the `NSToolbarDelegate` protocol and have an instance of that class be the delegate of your toolbar. This delegate would, for example, implement `-toolbar:itemForItemIdentifier:willBeInsertedIntoToolbar:`, which returns an `NSToolbarItem` instance for a given identifier, potentially creating that item on demand. By doing this, you’re preparing your delegate to return a toolbar item when the toolbar asks it for the item corresponding to an identifier.

Having done that, you can programatically add a new toolbar item to the toolbar by sending `-[NSToolbar insertItemWithItemIdentifier:atIndex]` to the toolbar instance. The identifier string argument should match the one used in the paragraph above. If you need to remove an item, send `-[NSToolbar removeItemAtIndex:]` to the toolbar.

This is described with examples in the [Adding and Removing Toolbar Items](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Toolbars/Tasks/AddRemoveToolbarItems.html) section of the [Toolbar Programming Topics for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Toolbars/) document.

Comment: why so complicated, Apple?

Comment: @Lukas because back when NSToolbar was designed, techniques like this were necessary to reduce RAM consumption. This was a standard pattern and how _everything_ in Cocoa used to work. Only the new stuff doesn't work like this.